# get text by tag properties using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html

Html:

```
 <h1 something="true">I am text</h1>
```

Now what i want to do is extract the text with something="true" but i dont know how am i suppose to do it

If the something will be id it would be simpler but what if it isn't..can we still extract the text using getElementBy method.

**Jsfiddle** demo would be appreciated.

Edit:I want to extract the word I am text

Comment: "Jsfiddle demo would be appreciated." Really? What have /you/ tried?

Comment: i told...extraction of text into variable

Comment: @SasukeKun: Terry want to tell you to show your effort... what have you tried but not work, we can help investigating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using jQuery, you can use document.querySelector.

```
var text = document.querySelector('[something="true"]').innerHTML;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathggns/WErpr/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), but you should use html5 `data-something`

Comment: OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: "get text by tag properties using javascript or jquery"

Comment: I see now :). Then he is just too lazy to add the tag. Besides being too lazy to read the documentation.

Comment: i am not lazy...actually i am not that good at jquery.
So i might mess it up so i asked for a demo

Answer (score 0):

It'd probably better to use the `data-` attributes:

```
<h1 data-something="true">I am text</h1>
```

And accessing that value would simply be:

```
var getSomething = $('h1').data('something');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/